# What happens to data on unpolled datagram sockets?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, udp

I've tried to google this, but can't find anything.

If I have a long running program that listens to a datagram (UDP) socket. If data is sent to my socket, but my program does not poll for it or read from it, what happens to the data in Linux kernel? Will it eventually timeout and be discarded by the kernel, or does it stay there until my program exits or does poll/read the socket?

Comment: Are you asking out of general interest, or do you need that for some application you're developing? Because if the latter, it might not be too hard to just test it, and you'd know for sure the results were what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

it eventually timeout and be discarded by the kernel. This is the principle of UDP packet loss.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Perhaps you can edit your post and add a link to official kernel documentation where this behaviour is specified?